# Pandas setting entries for selected values in column A in another column B

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an **elegant** way to make the following query:

```
# Given
original_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,5],'B':[2,4,6]})
A_values_where = [1,3]
B_values_setTo = [10,11]

# Wished output
target_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,5],'B':[10,11,6]})
```

Should be self-explanatory, but to be precise: Wherever a value in 'A' of 'A_values_where' is found set column 'B' in the same row to the value in 'B_values_setTo'. Most importantly, the values in 'Three' shall not be touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created from lists for always correct matching by values in both lists (also working if sublist match):

```
d = dict(zip(A_values_where, B_values_setTo))

original_df['B'] = original_df['A'].map(d).fillna(original_df['B'])
print (original_df)
   A     B
0  1  10.0
1  3  11.0
2  5   6.0
```

If order is always same is possible use this alternative, but failed in general data, so first solution is prefered:

```
original_df.loc[original_df['A'].isin(A_values_where), 'B'] = B_values_setTo
```

Comment: You have no idea how much work you have saved me. Thank you so much.